# Overriding inherited generic methods

Tags: c#, generics

I have this code in base class

```
 protected virtual bool HasAnyStuff<TObject>(TObject obj) where TObject:class 
  {
      return false;
  }
```

In child class I am overriding

```
protected override bool HasAnyStuff<Customer>(Customer obj) 
  {
    //some stuff
      if Customer.sth etc
      return false;
  }
```

I am getting this error

> '''Type parameter declaration must be an identifier not a type'''

What is it I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can't override a generic method's type parameter in a derived class.  To achieve a similar functionality, one option is to have your base class be a generic class, and have your derived class such as

```
class Derived : BaseClass<Customer>
{
     protected override bool HasAnyStuff(Customer customer)
     {
         // ...
     }
}
```

where `BaseClass` is declared as

```
class BaseClass<T> where T : class
{
    // ...
    protected virtual bool HasAnyStuff(T obj)
    {
         // ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, depending on exactly how your derived class is being used, you can just override the `HasAnyStuff` method with a non-generic `Customer` argument.

```
public bool HasAnyStuff(Customer customer)
{
    // ...
}
```

However, note that the new `HasAnyStuff` will not be called if you are not working with an instance of `DerivedClass`.  That is to say,

```
BaseClass foo = new DerivedClass();
foo.HasAnyStuff(new Customer());
```

will call `BaseClass`'s generic method, not `DerivedClass`'s non-generic method.

Answer (score 6):

Similar to John Carpenter's answer, you can override the generic method with the same generic method, but simply use the `as` operator to check and cast it to the desired type. This has the added benefit of using null-testing to check if the conversion worked.

Base Class

```
protected virtual bool HasAnyStuff<TObject>(TObject obj)
{
    .... // base implementation
}
```

Inherited Class

```
protected override bool HasAnyStuff<TObject>(TObject obj)
{
    var customer = obj as Customer;
    if (customer == null) // conversion failed. object is not of type Customer
    {
        return base.HasAnyStuff(obj);
    }

    .... // do stuff with the customer
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, also I found this documentation on type casting in general helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast

Answer (score 0):

I had the same use case that you are looking for.  There is a generic method on the base class and I want to override the method for just a single type.  For all other types, I wanted the method to behave the same way.  Here is a simple example based on your question.

```
class BaseClass
{
    protected virtual bool HasAnyStuff<TObject>(TObject obj)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    protected override bool HasAnyStuff<TObject>(TObject obj)
    {
        if (typeof(TObject) != typeof(AlarmTran)) return base.HasAnyStuff<TObject>(obj);

        //some stuff
        //if Customer.sth etc
        return false;
    }
}
```

You may also invert the `if` logic to handle multiple overrides for many different types.

```
protected override bool HasAnyStuff<TObject>(TObject obj)
{
    if (typeof(TObject) == typeof(AlarmTran))
    {
        //some stuff
        //if Customer.sth etc
        return false;
    }
    else if (typeof(TObject) == typeof(...))
    {
        ...
        return ...;
    }

    return base.HasAnyStuff<TObject>(obj);
}
```