# Type parameter declaration must be  identifier not a type

Tags: c#, generics

```
public abstract class BaseDocumentLayer : IDocumentLayer
{                                                       
   public IDocumentLayer NextLayer { get;set;}

   public virtual Document<T, U> ProcessDocument<T, U>(Document<T, U> document) {
      if(NextLayer != null)
         document = NextLayer.ProcessDocument(document);
      return document;          
   }
}

public override Document<GenericDatabaseDTO, GenericDatabaseConstants.ActionType> ProcessDocument<GenericDatabaseDTO, GenericDatabaseConstants.ActionType>(Document<GenericDatabaseDTO, GenericDatabaseConstants.ActionType> document)
{       
    return base.ProcessDocument<GenericDatabaseDTO, 
}

public static class GenericDatabaseConstants 
{    
    public enum ActionType 
    {                
       CreateGeneric,
       ReadGeneric,
       UpdateGeneric,
       DeleteGeneric,               
    }
}
```

Why do I get the error: Type paramter declaration must be an identifier not a type?

[image]

Error1:

```
public override Document<GenericDatabaseDTO, GenericDatabaseConstants.ActionType> ProcessDocument(Document<GenericDatabaseDTO, GenericDatabaseConstants.ActionType> document)
{   

    return base.ProcessDocument(document);
}
```

Error   1   'GenericDocumentLayer2.Document.GenericDatabase.ProcessLayer.ProcessDocument(GenericDocumentLayer2.TypeDefinition.Document)': no suitable method found to override

I have not changed my origin BaseLayer.ProcessDocument method

**UPDATE**

```
public void Add(GenericDatabaseField field) {
            var dto = new GenericDatabaseDTO();
            dto.Field = field;
            dto.Id = "test";

            var document = new Document<GenericDatabaseDTO, GenericDatabaseConstants.ActionType>(dto, GenericDatabaseConstants.ActionType.CreateGeneric, null);
            IDocumentLayer layer = DocumentFactory.CreateDocumentLayers();
                                          // The generic ProcessDocument is never called just the base version
        document = layer.ProcessDocument<GenericDatabaseDTO, GenericDatabaseConstants.ActionType>(document);                
    }
```

Comment: Can you make BaseDocumentLayer generic so that it specifies what T and U are.  You can then in your derived class extend it with the specific class you're after.

Comment: Why is this tagged [opentype]? What does this have to do with OpenType fonts?

Comment: of course I have seen this duplicate title when I drafted this question. But my context is totally different.

Comment: @M Afifi I tried but it did not help because the derived method is never called instead only the base method. I have a chain of layers and they all implement the same interface. I have no chance to access the derived instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't override a generic method for a specific type. This is possible with C++'s templates but not with C#'s generics.

To make your code compile, change it to this:

```
public override Document<TDTO, TActionType> ProcessDocument<TDTO, TActionType>(Document<TDTO, TActionType> document)
```

This will compile, but it will override the base type method for all generic arguments.

If you want to provide a special implementation just for one type, you can add a non-generic overload and internally call the generic version after the special handling:

```
public Document<GenericDatabaseDTO, GenericDatabaseConstants.ActionType> ProcessDocument(Document<GenericDatabaseDTO, GenericDatabaseConstants.ActionType> document)  
{
    // some special handling for this special case here...

    return base.ProcessDocument(document);
}
```

However, please note that this will break in polymorphic scenarios like this one:

Assume the methods above are implemented in `Derived`. `Derived` is derived from `Base`

```
GenericDatabaseDTO dto = /*...*/;
GenericDatabaseConstants.ActionType actionType = /*...*/;

Derived d = new Derived();
Base b = d;

// calls the non-generic version with special handling from Derived:
d.ProcessDocument(dto, actionType);
// calls the generic version from Base:
b.ProcessDocument(dto, actionType);
```

Comment: If I use your code and do not put the "<..>" after the ProcessDocument of  ProcessDocument(Document<GenericDatabaseDTO it does not compile.

Comment: @Pascal: I am sorry, I don't understand your comment. Please show the exact line that doesn't compile along with the exact compiler error.

Comment: See Error1 at init post.

Comment: @Pascal: The `override` in my sample code was invalid. It needs to be removed. Please check.

Comment: Do you have an ideal Abluft error2?

Comment: @Pascal: This is a new question. Please post it as such. And don't forget to accept and upvote my answer.

Comment: yes Daniel I will do. sorry but my last question was done via smartphone...

Comment: ok now I faced the problem you spoke of. Tehis code calls the generic base version:  document = layer.ProcessDocument<GenericDatabaseDTO, GenericDatabaseConstants.ActionType>(document); but actually it should call the derived d.ProcessDocument. I know where the problem lies. Its because the DerivedLayer is not used when I call the layer.ProcessDocument. The layer is of type IDocumentLayer not from the concrete class type. You have any good advice on this? else I have to go with the override ProcessDocument<T,U>

Comment: I updated my init post with the code sample why it does not work. see my comment before

Comment: I found this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676940/overriding-inherited-generic-methods sadly it seems even when I make the base class generic its never calling the overriden/new method ONLY when I use an instance of the derived class. This is not possible for me :/

Comment: @Pascal: Stop putting new stuff in this question. Your original question has been answered long ago. Create a new one!

Comment: ah ok I thought your first "stop putting new stuff" was only because of the error2.