# Properly update subtypes

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I'm trying to write `Update` method that will update properties of a given object. To make the example simple imagine, I have these classes:

```
public class Person
{
     public string Name;

     public virtual void Update(Person person)
     {
        this.Name= person.Name;
     }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
     public string Id;

     public override void Update(Person person)
     {
        base.Update(person);
        var employee = person as Employee;
        this.Id= employee.Id;
     }
 }

public class Manager: Employee
{
     public string Title;

     public override void Update(Person person)
     {
        base.Update(person);
        var manager = person as Manager;
        this.Title = manager.Title;
     }
 }
```

This is just a dump example to say: I have a deep level of inheritance. In each level there are more properties added to the subtype. I'm trying to write an `update` method for all subtypes.

Casting inside `Update` method does not seem good idea.
I'm thinking to use use [generic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676940/overriding-inherited-generic-methods). That would be fine if I have 2 level of inheritance. But If inheritance is  too deep, I need to make all subtypes generic down to last child.

Is there a better way to do `Update`?

Comment: Employee : Person ?

Comment: What class is Parent? Did you mean to write `class Employee : Person`?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish and why.

Comment: @David This is just a dump example to say: I have a deep level of inheritance. In each level there are more properties added to the subtype. I'm trying to write an `update` method for all subtypes.

Comment: Is this code compiled at all? It seems broken to me

Comment: use abstract class to write functions that is common to all subtypes. If you need to change the implementation, do change in sub class

Comment: @David I fixed inheritance part

Comment: @TazbirBhuiyan ok. I have `update` as abstract. What type of parameter should I pass to the method?

Comment: @Mhd  you can pass Person object as parameter. But, It depends on purpose of your code. Are you trying to update Base object's data or child object's data?

Comment: @TazbirBhuiyan I'm trying to update both base and child object's data. That's why I'm casting and calling base method

Comment: Good enough. Every child class is a Parent class by born. So, you will have all properties of base from childs. BUt, remember, it's a one way journey. if it is 3-4-5 level. Level 3 won't be able to update data for 5. Make sure to understand that. For this problem. you might use some interface to access lower level data from parents.

Comment: @Mhd I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the casting by adding `Update` overloads for the subtypes, like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name;

    public virtual void Update(Person person)
    {
        this.Name = person.Name;
    }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public string Id;

    public virtual void Update(Employee employee)
    {
        base.Update(employee);
        this.Id = employee.Id;
    }
}

public class Manager: Employee
{
    public string Title;

    public void Update(Manager manager)
    {
        base.Update(manager);
        this.Title = manager.Title;
    }
}
```

A possible downside is that this leaves the base versions in place and usable at all levels, so now you can do this:

```
var p = new Person { ... }
var m = new Manager { ... }
m.Update(p); // Updates only the Name
```

Should you want to prevent this, then you'll have to override `Update(<base type> x)` in each subclass and throw some kind of (runtime) exception.

Comment: you get straight to the issue. I don't want to update a manager by person. So I'm expecting a compilation error when doing `m.Update(p);`. 
Also, When doing `m.Update(m1);`, I need to update the `Manager m` and all his props (Employee Id  and Person Name)

Comment: @Mhd, If you _don't want to update a manager by person_ but manager somehow inherits from person, then your rules are a bit ambigous. Anyone can cast a manager to a person, then what? Should'nt then the peraon be allowed to be updated by a person?